# Can the configuration for the embedded tomcat affect the external tomcat?

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, embedded-tomcat

I have a **Spring Boot Web** application In the configuration file, I configure the server (for local launch):

```
server:
   port: 8085
   tomcat:
   threads:
       max: 25
   servlet:
       context-path: /path
```

Can these settings somehow affect tomcat if it is not internal? I just assemble the war file and put it into a full-fledged tomcat.

For example, `port: 8085`, everything is obvious here, my war will not be able to change the port of an external tomcat, but for example, with `context-path : /path`, not everything is obvious.